# Typeset numbers as math

Tags: math-mode, fonts

I have the following code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\begin{document}
    \begin{theorem}~\\
        Text and something else: $j \in \{1, \ldots, J\}$
    \end{theorem}~\\
    Text and something else: $j \in \{1, \ldots, J\}$
    Text and something else: $\rm j \in \{1, \ldots, J\}$ 
\end{document}
```

I would like to have, that the `1` is always typed as the `J` (The first two times in italic, the last time in upright font. 
Is there an automated way - like a macro \one - that does this?

---

EDIT:

Since I figured out, that this is not what I want, I posted a new question:
[Typeset numbers as math and numbers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/410041/typeset-numbers-as-math-and-numbers)

Comment: numbers are not italicized in math, **by design**.  p.s. `\rm` is deprecated

Comment: Re the addition: use the standard setup and use `\mathit{1}` when you want the number in italics.

Comment: @egreg: This does not work, because in `\mathrm{\mathit{1}+j}` the `1` is in italic, but the `j` is in upright.

Comment: @tommsch What does that mean? If you want the number upright, don't use `\mathit`. But, as I've already said, it's a long standing tradition to typeset numbers *always* upright (and letters generally in italics).

Comment: @egreg: I do not want to think about, whether the surrounding math is in upright or italic. I just want my number `1` printed in the same style as the math around it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can, but it's a long standing tradition that numbers in math are typeset upright.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,thmtools}

\declaretheoremstyle[
  spaceabove=\topsep,
  spacebelow=\topsep,
  bodyfont=\itshape,
  break,
]{break}
\declaretheorem[
  style=break,
  name=Theorem,
]{theorem}

\DeclareSymbolFont{italic}{OT1}{\familydefault}{m}{it}
\SetSymbolFont{italic}{bold}{OT1}{\familydefault}{bx}{it}
\DeclareSymbolFontAlphabet{\mathit}{italic}

\DeclareMathSymbol{0}{\mathalpha}{italic}{`0}
\DeclareMathSymbol{1}{\mathalpha}{italic}{`1}
\DeclareMathSymbol{2}{\mathalpha}{italic}{`2}
\DeclareMathSymbol{3}{\mathalpha}{italic}{`3}
\DeclareMathSymbol{4}{\mathalpha}{italic}{`4}
\DeclareMathSymbol{5}{\mathalpha}{italic}{`5}
\DeclareMathSymbol{6}{\mathalpha}{italic}{`6}
\DeclareMathSymbol{7}{\mathalpha}{italic}{`7}
\DeclareMathSymbol{8}{\mathalpha}{italic}{`8}
\DeclareMathSymbol{9}{\mathalpha}{italic}{`9}
\DeclareMathSymbol{!}{\mathclose}{italic}{"21}


\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}
Text and something else: $j \in \{1, \ldots, J\}$
\end{theorem}

Text and something else: $j \in \{1, \ldots, J\}$

Text and something else: $j \in \{\mathrm{1, \ldots, J}\}$ 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. I see now,  that I asked the wrong question. If I want my `1` only typed as a letter in some places, (like that in the example), but in the other places (like in an equation $1+1 = 2$) like a number, how do I do that?

Comment: @tommsch Since egreg put in the effort to answer your original question, it would be best to ask your revised question as a completely new question, and to accept his answer as the proper answer to this question.