# Typeset numbers as math and numbers

Tags: math-mode, fonts

This is a follow up question to: [Typeset numbers as math](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/409886/typeset-numbers-as-math)

I am searching for a macro (could be named `\one`) which typesets the number `1`. The number `1` should be typesetted in the same style (upright or italic) as would variables (letters) would be typesetted.

I want this, because sometimes I write numbers in a math-environments which actually serve as variables.

Note: `\mathit{1}` does not work, since this types the number `1` always in italics, wheres in a `\mathrm` environment, it should be typed upright.

Comment: You practically answered the question yourself, just define `\newcommand{\one}{\ensuremath{\mathit{1}}}` and replace `1` by `\one` wherever you like to have an italic `1`. Personally I would not want to do that, and if I was forced to, I'd use `\newcommand{\ItalicOne}{\ensuremath{\mathit{1}}}`.

Comment: @marmot: That does not work, because in `\mathrm{\mathit{1}+j}`, the `1` is in italics, but the j is in upright.

Comment: I see. Apologies, I misinterpreted your question.

Comment: There are so many 1's that's quite unclear which ones you're referring to.

Comment: @egreg: I changed the way I asked my question now again. I hope it is clear now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Possibly this is what you're looking for:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,thmtools}

\declaretheoremstyle[
  spaceabove=\topsep,
  spacebelow=\topsep,
  bodyfont=\itshape,
  break,
]{break}
\declaretheorem[
  style=break,
  name=Theorem,
]{theorem}

\newcommand{\vardigit}[1]{%
  \ifnum\mathgroup<0 \mathit{#1}\else #1\fi
}
\newcommand{\0}{\vardigit{0}}
\newcommand{\1}{\vardigit{1}}
\newcommand{\2}{\vardigit{2}}
\newcommand{\3}{\vardigit{3}}
\newcommand{\4}{\vardigit{4}}
\newcommand{\5}{\vardigit{5}}
\newcommand{\6}{\vardigit{6}}
\newcommand{\7}{\vardigit{7}}
\newcommand{\8}{\vardigit{8}}
\newcommand{\9}{\vardigit{9}}


\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}
Text and something else: $j \in \{\1, \ldots, J\}$
\end{theorem}

Text and something else: $j \in \{\1, \ldots, J\}$

Text and something else: $j \in \{\mathrm{\1, \ldots, J}\}$ 

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to be able to input digits as such,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,thmtools}

\declaretheoremstyle[
  spaceabove=\topsep,
  spacebelow=\topsep,
  bodyfont=\itshape,
  break,
]{break}
\declaretheorem[
  style=break,
  name=Theorem,
]{theorem}

\makeatletter
\def\@temp#1{%
  \begingroup\lccode`~=`#1 \lowercase{%
    \endgroup
    \edef~%
  }{\noexpand\vardigit{\mathchar\the\mathcode`#1 }}
  \AtBeginDocument{\mathcode`#1="8000 }
}
\@temp{0}\@temp{1}\@temp{2}\@temp{3}\@temp{4}
\@temp{5}\@temp{6}\@temp{7}\@temp{8}\@temp{9}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\vardigit}[1]{%
  \ifnum\mathgroup<0 \mathit{#1}\else #1\fi
}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}
Text and something else: $j \in \{1, \ldots, J\}$
\end{theorem}

Text and something else: $j \in \{1, \ldots, J\}$

Text and something else: $j \in \{\mathrm{1, \ldots, J}\}$ 

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set the numbers from the same font as letters but in computer modern that may not be quite what you expect

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\DeclareMathSymbol{0}{\mathalpha}{letters}{`0}
\DeclareMathSymbol{1}{\mathalpha}{letters}{`1}
\DeclareMathSymbol{2}{\mathalpha}{letters}{`2}
\DeclareMathSymbol{3}{\mathalpha}{letters}{`3}
\DeclareMathSymbol{4}{\mathalpha}{letters}{`4}
\DeclareMathSymbol{5}{\mathalpha}{letters}{`5}
\DeclareMathSymbol{6}{\mathalpha}{letters}{`6}
\DeclareMathSymbol{7}{\mathalpha}{letters}{`7}
\DeclareMathSymbol{8}{\mathalpha}{letters}{`8}
\DeclareMathSymbol{9}{\mathalpha}{letters}{`9}

\begin{document}

$ abc1 + \mathrm {abc1} + \mathsf{abc1}$

\end{document}
```

Perhaps closer would be the font used for mathit

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}


\DeclareSymbolFont{mathit}   {OT1}{cmr} {m}{it}% could make it share a slot with \mathit
\DeclareMathSymbol{0}{\mathalpha}{mathit}{`0}
\DeclareMathSymbol{1}{\mathalpha}{mathit}{`1}
\DeclareMathSymbol{2}{\mathalpha}{mathit}{`2}
\DeclareMathSymbol{3}{\mathalpha}{mathit}{`3}
\DeclareMathSymbol{4}{\mathalpha}{mathit}{`4}
\DeclareMathSymbol{5}{\mathalpha}{mathit}{`5}
\DeclareMathSymbol{6}{\mathalpha}{mathit}{`6}
\DeclareMathSymbol{7}{\mathalpha}{mathit}{`7}
\DeclareMathSymbol{8}{\mathalpha}{mathit}{`8}
\DeclareMathSymbol{9}{\mathalpha}{mathit}{`9}

\begin{document}

$ abc1 + \mathrm {abc1} + \mathsf{abc1}$

\end{document}
```

Comment: Which is exactly what I suggested in the linked question.

Comment: @egreg I didn't look, :-)